# Pandas balance panel in efficient way (forward fill)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a [dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zexg1puknwcpjvg/balance.csv?dl=0) and I would like to balance it.

The datatypes are:

```
TIME_M        datetime64[ns]
genesis       datetime64[ns]
SYM_ROOT            category
BEST_BID             float64
BEST_ASK             float64
judgement     datetime64[ns]
DATE                   int64
TIME_S                object
MIDPRICE             float64
bps                  float64
spread               float64
diff         timedelta64[ns]
diff_sec               int64
increment              int64
dtype: object
```

The variable I want to balance is `increment`. I want all `increment` to have no gaps in between (i.e. `increment` can't be `1,2,5`, must be `1,2,3,4,5`). In the case there is only `1,2,5`, I want to fill in the rows where `increment` is equal to `3` and `4` with the row where `increment` is equal to `2`, i.e. forward fill.

Besides, I want the forward fill to be done in groups of SYM_ROOT and DATE.

However, my expand function turns out to be very inefficient.

```
def expand_gap(x):
    #function to expand gaps 
    #iterate through to find gaps
    x['tmp_diff']=x['increment'].shift(-1)-x['increment']
    tmp_df=x[x['tmp_diff']>1]
    for i in range (0, len(tmp_df)):
        expand_incre = tmp_df.iloc[i,tmp_df.columns.get_loc('increment')]
        target_incre = tmp_df.iloc[i,tmp_df.columns.get_loc('increment')]+tmp_df.iloc[i,tmp_df.columns.get_loc('tmp_diff')]
        while (target_incre-expand_incre)>1:
            tmp_row=tmp_df.iloc[i:i+1]
            new_row=tmp_row.copy()
            expand_incre=expand_incre+1
            new_row['increment'].iloc[0]=expand_incre
            x=x.append(new_row)
    return x

df=df.groupby(['SYM_ROOT','DATE']).apply(expand_gap)
```

It takes a long time to balance the 1,000,000 rows of data. However, in reality, I have significantly more data to balance than that. Any idea how to achieve a efficient balancing?

I know it has something to do with appending to dataframes, which is a slow operation.

Any idea how to do it efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you can create first a dataframe with column "increment" filled as you need

```
max_lim = 20
my_list=list(range(1,max_lim))
my_array = np.array(my_list).reshape(max_lim-1, 1)
df = pd.DataFrame(my_array, columns=["increment"])
```

then you can join it with your dataframe.

```
df=df.merge(tmp_df)
```

After that, you should be able to achieve your goal using fillna:

```
df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Do I join it by each group?

Comment: I put max_lim =20 just as example, it should be max(tmp_df.increment). You should have only two dataframe to join, df and temp_df

Comment: I think it should be outer join and specify the key to be `increment`? I tried to edit it but it somehow got rejected ...

Comment: `df=df.merge(tmp_df,on="increment",how="outer")` @Giuseppe Bonavita

Comment: yes, you need outer join - or left join. and I believe increment is not necessary as id the only column shared between the two dataframes.